# JPA - Many to One where Child has the Parent id

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

#### Sample

Parent class

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
private List<Child> childs;
```

Child class

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
private Parent parent;
```

I assign the child objects to the parent, then persist the parent.

#### Problem

The parent and child are being saved, however, the `parent` field from the child id is saved as null.

#### Expected

I expected both entities to be saved with a value assigned to the `parent` field.

#### Temporal Solution

Well, if I persist the parent without the childs, then assign the childs and merge the parent, it all works, but I was wondering if all that could be done in a single persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you set one side relation only. You have to set

```
child.setParent(parent);
parent.getChilds().add(child); // to avoid NullPoinerException childs have to be not null
```

And then persist `child`

Comment: About the last part regarding to persist the child, in my case they are a list, do I persist every child in there besides the parent? is that because the child is the one with the parent id?

Comment: You can persist parent instead of child